# Why does Stack Overflow not have an FAQ

Tags: support

Why does Stack Overflow not have an FAQ where it concerns questions asked on the main site, and can one please be added?

It really disappointing that a Q&A site doesn't have an FAQ that is part of the page. In fact no  Stack Exchange site has an FAQ why is this? Could this be considered for the future?

Comment: Meta is the FAQ ... isn't it?

Comment: I don't really think so

Comment: Question that often get duplicated by users

Comment: We *had* a FAQ, but noone read it. We replaced it with a help center and a tour, but apparently that's not something *you* read or found adequate. Can you explain why a FAQ should be added back?

Comment: There is the 'frequent' tab on tags; this fills the role of automated FAQ collection. An overall FAQ for all of SO would be **massive** as there are too many different subjects people ask questions about.

Comment: Because I often wish to find questions with the same question Im looking for so I can see a more broad answer.

Comment: Please give a concrete example.

Comment: Similar questions will often be linked in the comments, as well as in the sidebar on the right, under "Linked", and if you're lucky, "Related".

Comment: My example is say I'm looking for an answer on reading arrays to a file but I want to see Several ways of doing it I could search it in the FAQ.

Comment: The site already has search functionality, how would your concept of "FAQ" differ from it?

Comment: Meta --> instant answers to any question (for the most part).

Comment: Could you please edit your question with an example of exactly what this "FAQ" you're talking about is, and how you'd use it? It is completely unclear what you mean after reading your question and comments.

Comment: @Mat Tried to clarify it slightly based on Shog's answer and the OP's response to it.

Comment: Not sure what ask, but there's a faq tag over on [meta.se] that contains many questions about how these sites work...

Answer (score 10):

The FAQ - as in, questions that are frequently duplicated/referenced - lives here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent

You can even narrow it down by tag:

- [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=frequent)
- [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=frequent)
- [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- etc.

The C++ community on Stack Overflow has taken this a step further, and organized a subset of common questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq

Finally, many communities list common beginner questions / resources in their tag wikis. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info), ['nother example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Thank you! But it would be good 2 search this list

Comment: Fastest gun in the west syndrome? Based on his comments, I don't think he's really looking for a FAQ. First figure out what the OP wants, and then, only *then* post answer..

Comment: Might want to try [reading the comments yourself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252103/why-does-stackoverflow-not-have-an-faq/252104?noredirect=1#comment6383_252103) before leaving any, @Karoly. I do this all damn day; I read quickly...

Comment: Just use the normal search, @curlip - unless you *know* what you're looking for has already been asked many times, you'll get better results. And stuff that has been often-referenced will tend to rank highly under the default sort as well.

Comment: If you read further, you'll see comments that completely contradict it. (update: looks like you did ;)

Comment: I disagree; the search doesn't work particularly well to find often-referenced questions. Even when I know the **exact** question I want to close as a duplicate of, the search works less well for me than going through the first 3 or 4 pages of the Frequent tab (although just using Google is usually better than that.)

Comment: Now how do we get people to look at those FAQs before asking "Java if statement doesn't work" for the 10,000th time?

Comment: @Shog9 - Frequent is not FAQ, it's Frequently Linked, not Frequently Asked.  I think what differentiates a FAQ is that a FAQ is curated, not automatically generated by an arbitrary criteria that may or may not be appropriate.

Comment: You're thinking of "Frequently Answered Questions", @Erik. Regardless, the defining factor of a FAQ - auto-generated or otherwise - is that it isn't read by most of the folks who would benefit from it.

Comment: @Shog9 - Touche